# Every finite subset of a non-empty totally ordered set has both upper and lower bounds

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

> Prove Every finite subset of a non-empty totally ordered set has both upper and lower bounds.

By completeness axiom every nonempty subset of real numbers that is bounded from above (respectively from below) has a supremum (respectively infimum) , a finite totally ordered set has finitely many elements and it's always possible to find a supremum or infimum of that set , and even upper or lower bounds, but I don't know how to prove that, because even completeness axiom consider the special case of a totally ordered set which is the set of real numbers, but what about the case where our totally ordered set is the power set of a specific set?

Can someone prove this statement?

Comment: Did you try induction on the number of elements?

Comment: @I did not , seems a good way, but I guess there should be another way. indeed I don't know how to use induction here since I don't have any specific totally ordered set

Comment: The power set is not totally ordered, although the statement is true for the powerset. Try proving it for pairs and using induction on the size of the set.

Answer (score 3):

**Proof**: (by induction on the cardinality of your finite set)

Let $P(n)$: *any set with $n$ elements has a sup and an inf that both belong to your set.*

P(1) is true: indeed if $A=\{a\}$ then $a=\sup A = \inf A$, and $a \in A$.

P(2) is true (I will need this later!): If $A = \{a,b\}$ then assume WLG that $a\leq b$. Then $\inf A = a$ and $\sup A = b$, and both are in $A$.

Assume $P(n)$ holds, that is, every set with $n$ elements has a min and a max. Take a $B$ with $n+1$ elements. Pick $a \in B$, and define $A = B \backslash \{a\}$. By induction hypothesis $A$ has a max and a min from $A$. Now,
$$
\inf B = \inf\{a,\inf A\}, \quad and \quad \sup B = \sup \{a,\sup A\} \,
$$
which by $P(2)$ exist. These sup and inf belong to $B$: Let me do $\sup B$ case only. Either $\sup B = a$, or, $\sup B = \sup A$. In the former case, $a \in B$, and we are done. In the latter case, by step $P(n)$ we know that $\sup A \in A$. But $A \subset B$, thus, $\sup A \in B$. This proves $P(n+1)$, and ends the induction. $\Box $

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be your finite set, say with $n$ elements. The total order of the ambient space induces a total order on $X$. Thus you can order the elents $x_i$ of $X$ so that $x_1< x_2<\dots< x_n$. Then $x_1$ is the minimum (hence a lower bound) and $x_n$ is the maximum (hence an upper bound).

In order to sort the elements of $X$ in an oredered way you can use the following algorithm:

Step $(1)$ Number the elements of $X$ as $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and go to next step.

Step $(2)$ Compare $x_1$ with $x_2$.

If $x_1>x_2$ then switch them and restart from Step $(2)$.

If $x_1<x_2$  go to next step.

Step $(3)$ Compare $x_2$ with $x_3$.

If $x_2>x_3$ then switch them and restart from Step $(2)$.

If $x_2<x_3$ go to next step.

...

Step $(n)$ Compare $x_{n-1}$ with $x_n$.
If $x_{n-1}>x_n$ then switch them and restart from Step $(2)$.

If $x_{n-1}<x_n$ STOP.

The numbering you get when you stop is exactly that given by the order. Indeed, when you stop, then you passed all the checks of any Step $(i)$, and thus $x_{i}<x_{i+1}$.

Comment: And I thought BubbleSort was inefficient! At least it doesn't require you start over at the top with every exchange. (Of course, efficiency has nothing to do with your purpose here: as long at the algorithm will eventually work, it proves the result.)