# Problem with a theorem related to upper/lower bounds and totally ordered sets.

Tags: induction, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds) states:

> Every finite subset of a non-empty totally ordered set has both upper and lower bounds.

First of all I don't know why the totally ordered set should be $\color{red}{\text{non-empty}}$ , because if it is an empty set then since the only subset of an empty set is the empty set itself, implies the subset is indeed an empty set, therefore we have a finite subset (with cardinality zero) of a totally ordered set,and we know that an empty set has both upper/lower bounds (by definition it does not have any sup/inf), hence the theorem is true even when the totally ordered set is empty,so why we need to say non-empty?

Notice that the theorem does not claim that every non-empty finite subset of a totally ordered set **contains** both upper and lower bounds, so showing that our subset contains a sup/inf or max/min would not be enough, since we need to consider a more general case :where either the upper/lower bound do belong to the subset or they don't.(**It would be nice if someone give me an example of a finite set that has upper/lower bounds but they don't belong to the set**)

---

I tried to prove the theorem using induction:

Define $P(k):=$ Every subset containing $k$ elements of a non-empty totally ordered set **has** both upper and lower bounds.

Where $k$ is a natural number.

- The base case would be an empty set,an emepty set has both upper/lower bounds, so the theorem is true for $P(0)$

Now assume the preposition is true for $0\le k\le n$, then consider the case $P(n+1)$:

- For simplicity I denote a set with cardinality $n+1$ with $B$ and define $B$ as:

$$B:=A \cup \left\{a\right\}$$

Where $\left|A\right|=n$.

The upper bound of $B$ is either the upper bound of $A$ or $a$ (by assumption upper/lower bound of $A$ exist), if upper bound of $B$ is the upper bound of $A$ then we are done, otherwise it would be $a$ which can be seen that the upper bound of $B$ does exist,so it can be concluded that the preposition is true for every $k$ natural.

---

I need a verification for my proof.

Note: the theorem has been already posted by me ,but here I give a proof and I explain the problem I have with the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all I don't know why the totally ordered set should be non-empty

If $L$ is totally ordered, and $A \subseteq L$, then $A$ is bounded if and only if there exists $b,c \in L$ such that for all $a \in A, b \le a \le c$.

If $L$ is empty, then there is no $b, c \in L$ to satisfy the definition. It doesn't matter that $A$ is empty too.

> It would be nice if someone give me an example of a finite set that has upper/lower bounds but they don't belong to the set

Easy: The set $\{1\}$ has lower bound $0$ and upper bound $2$.
Of course, the supremum and infimum of $\{1\}$ are both $1$, but you didn't say the bounds has to be extreme.

And if you are thinking I am just playing word games, you are right. But that is the real point here: so are you. No one claimed that there are finite sets which do not contain their extrema. Just because the author did not explicitly mention them does not mean they are claiming these do not always exist.

> so showing that our subset contains a sup/inf or max/min would not be enough, since we need to consider a more general case :where either the upper/lower bound do belong to the subset or they don't.

No. An upper bound for $A$ is an upper bound for $A$ whether or not it is in $A$. So if $A$ has a maximum, that maximum is an upper bound, and since $A \subseteq L$, that upper bound is in $L$, and therefore $A$ is bounded above in $L$. Similar remarks apply to lower bounds.

You mention suprema and infima, but unlike maxima and minima, suprema and infima do not need to be in the set. In fact that is the difference between maxima and suprema, and between infima and minima. A maximum is a supremum that is contained in the set, and a minimum is an infima that is in the set.

Also, a set can be bounded and not have either one. For example, in the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$, the set $\{x\mid x \in \Bbb Q, x^2 < 2\}$ is bounded, but has no supremum or infimum.

- The base case would be an empty set,an emepty set has both upper/lower bounds, so the theorem is true for $P(0)$

As long as $L$ is not empty, this is true, since any element of $L$ satisfies the conditions to be both an upper and lower bound. If $L = \emptyset$, it is false.

> The upper bound of B is either the upper bound of A or a (by assumption upper/lower bound of A exist), if upper bound of B is the upper bound of A then we are done, otherwise it would be a which can be seen that the upper bound of B does exist,so it can be concluded that the preposition is true for every k natural.

You've got the right idea here, but you have not demonstrated it. Effectively, you just said "it's true because it's true".

What you need to do is something like this:

"Let $b$ be an upper bound of $A$. Either $a > b$ or $a \le b$.

If $a > b$, then for all $x \in B$, either $x \ne a$, so $x \in A$ and $x \le b < a$, or $x = a$, so $x \le a$. In either case for all $x \in B, x\le a$, and $a$ is an upper bound.

Otherwise, if $a \le b$, then for all $x \in B$, either $x \in A$, so $x \le b$, or $x = a$, so $x\le b$. In either case, $b$ is an upper bound.

Therefore $B$ has an upper bound."

Comment: Should not you say "let $b$ be an upper bound of $\color{red}{B}$.either...."? instead of saying "let $b$ be an upper bound of $\color{red}{A}$.either...."?

Comment: The *whole point* here is to *prove $B$ has an upper bound*. You can't say "let $b$ be an upper bound of $B$" until you've proved $B$ has one.  That is the main reason why your argument amounts to claiming "it's true because it's true". You start off by assuming the very thing you are supposed to show.

Comment: You say "If $L$ is totally ordered, and $A \subseteq L$, then $A$ is bounded if and only if there exists $b,c \in L$ such that for all $a \in A, b \le a \le c$"$\underbrace{a \in A}_\textrm{p},\underbrace{b \le a \le c}_\textrm{q}$ ,

Comment: or equivalently : $\underbrace{a \in A}_\textrm{p},\underbrace{b \le a \le c}_\textrm{q}$ , or equivalently : **if** $\underbrace{a \in A}_\textrm{p}$ **then** $\underbrace{b \le a \le c}_\textrm{q}$,this statement is wrong if $p$ is $\color{red}{\text{true}}$ and $q$ is $\color{red}{\text{wrong}}$ , in other words the statement is wrong: **if** $\underbrace{a \in A}_\textrm{p}$ **but** either $\underbrace{b \nleq a \;\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\; a\nleq c}_\textrm{¬ q}$   , So are we able to find such $a$ containing in $A$ such that this $a$ does not satisfy $q$ ?

Comment: well since $A$ does not have any element not satisfying the condition, so the statement is always true.

Comment: You are completely overlooking what comes *first*: $\exists b,c \in L$ If this is *false*, the entire statement is false. The phrase "$\exists P(x)$ such that $Q(x)$" for some predicates $P, Q$ is shorthand for $(\exists x)(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$. So for $A$ to be bounded above in $L$, there has to exist some $b$ such that $\underbrace{b \in L}_P$ *and* $\underbrace{\forall a\in A, a \le b}_Q$ If for every $b$, $P$ is false, it doesn't matter if $Q$ is true or false, $P \wedge Q$ will still be false. Since it is false for every $b$, the entire statement is false.

Comment: Nice explanation, can you look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540275/every-finite-subset-of-a-non-empty-totally-ordered-set-has-both-upper-and-lower/3554054#3554054) and look at the answer from the user Behnam Esmayli, the author of this answer indeed  proves the Belongingness of the bounds ,well first of all It should be mentioned that the theorem does not mention in  $\color{red}{\text{Belongingness}}$, it just claims about $\color{red}{\text{existence}}$ , that's why I think the answer should not be the proof of the theorem (well the answer is true itself)

Comment: So the argument actually proves a little *more* than the theorem requires. That is not some issue. It still proves the theorem. The only "flaw" I see in his proof is that it skips over several small details (for example, showing that $\sup \{a, \sup A\}$ is indeed the supremum of $B$), but this is only a flaw when speaking to those who do not yet understand the importance of those details and how to properly fill them in. Behnam skipped them because they assumed you knew. I included them because your proffered proof here flubbed them by assuming $B$ was bounded.

Comment: So any bounded set has both sup/inf and any set that has sup/inf is bounded?I guess that's the reason why the author showed that a finite subset of a non-empty totally ordered set has sup/inf because it's equivalent to show that such a finite subset is bounded

Comment: In general it is not true that bounded implies the existence of the infimum and supremum. $\{r \in \Bbb Q \mid r^2 < 2\}$ as a subset of $\Bbb Q$ is a classic example where it fails. It is true that bounded set in $\Bbb R$ will have extrema, but that is a special property of $\Bbb R$, not of totally ordered sets in general. In the other direction, having an infimum/supremum does mean the set it bounded, because these extrema are themselves bounds. Behnam showed the particular bounds they did because because those were the bounds that could be demonstrated to exist. Being in the set was bonus.

Comment: But how is it possible a set with inf/ sup to be unbounded? using the definition, inf of a  set $\mathbb S$ denoted $u$ is an element (of...) such that $\forall s \in \mathbb S:u \le s$, and $u$ is the greatest $\color{red}{\text{lower bound}}$ for $\mathbb S$, it means that $u$ already is a lower bound (with the extra property that is being the greatest) the same can be said for sup, so how a set with sup/ inf is not always bounded?

Comment: Please note that in my previous comment, I said *having an infimum/supremum does mean the set is bounded, because these extrema are themselves bounds* (except I corrected the typo I noticed too late in that comment). It is "bounded $\implies$ existence of extrema" that I said was false in general, not the other way around.

Comment: yes that's right (well existence of sup/inf implies the boundness (these sup/inf can be maximum/minimum resp)), and in your last step of the proof is $a$ an element in $A$?

Comment: No - I was completing your proof, and you intrduced $a$ as the element of $B$ not in $A$: $$B=A\cup\{a\}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the post (you are one of the most patient users here I've ever seen , because you answered every single comments of mine (+1))

Comment: That is because it was obvious you were trying to learn, and even when the communication went awry, you were willing to listen rather than ignoring what I said in favor of maintaining a misconception. Had these not been true (of which unfortunately I've had a lot of experience), you would have found my patience much shorter.